# Can someone fill in some missing letters?

Tags: translation, transcription

[image]
What I think this says:

---

Friedrich Adel Ferdinand Torsten Graf Posadowsky-Wehner, Freiherr v. Postelwitz

Kgl. Preuss Oberst und Kommandeur des (2 Oster.) Gren Rgt. 13

geb. am 12 Aug. 1864
u Rinkowken
gefallen am 7 Okt. 1914
i Wodziki

Al
Chef des Generalstabs eines Reservecorps die warb er sichin der Schlacht bei Tannenberg unschätzbare Verdienst.

Gros e Führergaber sind m__m begrab in.

---

but several letters I had to guess at, and I can't guess what the plant is hiding.  Deepl said it was "Great leaders are buried with him" which makes little sense and Google was worse.

I'd be grateful for assistance, and for the meaning of the last line.  (I don't speak German and I'm not very good in Dutch.)

Comment: I tried to find something biographical online, but only came up with other people having the same surname.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because answering the question will not improve any ones insights, how to achieve such a task the next time on his own. It's a single case help which will not help in any case of the 1000 similar tasks in future.

Comment: "Führergaben" can be translated by "leadership" or "leadership skills".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I give it a shot:

> Friedrich Adolf
> Ferdinand Torsten
> Graf Posadowsky
> Wehner
> Freiherr v. Postelwitz
> Kgl. Preuss Oberst
> und Kommandeur
> des (2. Ostpr.) Gren Rgt №3
> geb. am 2. August 1864
> in Rinkowken
> gefallen am 7. Okt. 1914
> bei Wodzilki
> in Verteidiung der Szeszupalinie

> Als
> Chef des Generalstabs
> eines Reservecorps
> erwarb er sich in der
> Schlacht bei Tannenberg
> unschätzbare Verdienste
> Grosse Führergaben
> sind mit ihm begraben

This roughly translates to

> Friedrich Adolf Ferdinand Torsten Graf Posadowsky Wehner Freiher von Postelwitz, Royal Prussian Oberst and commander of the (2nd East Prussian) infantry regiment no. 3, born 2nd August 1864 in Rinkowken, died in battle on 7 October 1914 near Wodzilki in defence of the Szueszupa line.

> As chief of the general staff of a reserve corp he gained invaluable merit in the battle at Tannenberg. Great leadership is burried here with him.

Comment: I'm sure that's it.  Comparing the photo to your text, I can see the letters I had misinterpreted.  And Wodziłki (with Ł) not only exists but is about forty kilometers from the cemetery.  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it's not Reg. 13 but Reg. no 3. Hard to make out correctly.

Comment: @CarstenS you are right. On closer inspection there are two well-withered 'e'. Also it is 'bei', agreed. Thanks!

Comment: Definitely Reg. no 3. See https://wiki.genealogy.net/Gren.R_3. And not "2. Öster.", but "2. Ostpr.".

Comment: There is a missing "N"  in "numero sign 3". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign.

Comment: It is "Postelwitz". https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posadowsky_(Adelsgeschlecht)

Comment: thanks @PaulFrost and @ kritikerderElche